# JavaDoc of xuggler plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, xuggler

Netbeans says that the java documentation for the method does not exist. Now there are many interfaces, classes and methods how to know the exact work of each and every method if documentation is not available??

Answer (score 0):

I found the documentation about xuggler on the internet with google :p
Here is the link :

http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/